# Как залить git проект в другой репозиторий?

Tags: git, github

Есть проект с git, он подключен к репозиторию и туда пушатся все коммиты, есть новый репозиторий, в который надо загрузить этот проект, в новом репозитории есть два файла - .gitignore и README.md. Я в git не очень силён, помогите как это правильно сделать.

Comment: Скопировать файлы из старого в новый?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зайти в какую нибудь пустую папку на локальном компе. Далее выполнить набор команд:

```
git clone --mirror git@oldserver:oldproject.git
cd oldproject.git
git remote add new git@newserver:newproject.git
git push --mirror new
```

адреса репозиториев заменить на свои (в моем случае они начинались на https). при этом .gitignore и README.md перезапишутся файлами из старого репозитория.

только что проверил это на своем github проекте.

Comment: спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @PROCODE если ответ вам помог, то [примите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) его пожалуйста